# How should I interpret a quadratic term in a logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, regression-coefficients

My understanding of a quadratic term in a regular regression is that it can be thought of as the rate of change, where the slope in the original feature x is adjusted by the amount in the quadratic term for each additional unit of x.

E.g. In a regular regression if age in years is associated with an increase in y of 10 and age ^2 is 2 then after 10/2 = 5 years the affect of age is doubled to +20 on y.

Have I understood the linear regression case correctly?

If so, how should I interpret a quadratic term for a logistic regression? If I have a feature x with a logit estimate of -0.010415882669274, and odds ratio of 0.242703979997507 and the corresponding values for the quadratic term of 0.0000903917003615193 for the logit estimate and 1.00009039578581 for the odds ratio.

How can I interpret the quadratic effect of x on y?

Comment: Take a look at [Ai and Norton (2003)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.197.5996&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and [Buis (2010)](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0194), and the discussions of these papers on this forum.